# Stop selection of element on background double-click

Tags: javascript, html, focus, double-click

I have a problem that when the background is double-clicked the first element is selected.

Check out this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cb6fjr7n/1/

`<input style="text" value="lala"/>`

If you double-click outside of the input the input will get selected, but it still doesn't have focus because you can't type.

I need to stop this behavior. I want no selection, no focus, no highlight or anything like that when double-clicking. And not just a cosmetic fix, I don't want the focus to move at all.
I still need to be able to input text in the input field though when the input itself is clicked upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the css property `user-select`

### Check out this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/34kuf1c1/

Comment: Thanks, but you misunderstood me(my fault). I still want to be able to enter text in the input field. It's just the unwanted selection of the double-click I want to disable.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! :D

Comment: I'm to much of a newbie to be able to upvote, but I have accepted it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add disabled to your input !

```
<input disabled style="text" value="lala"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but you misunderstood me(my fault). I still want to be able to enter text in the input field. It's just the unwanted selection of the double-click I want to disable.